# Sublime 2 Build System for CLISP in Windows (Cygwin)

Tags: windows, build, cygwin, sublimetext2, clisp

[I just figured out the answer to this question for myself, but it was a real pain, so I figured I should post it here so the next person like me can hopefully find it.]

How do you make a Sublime 2 build system for CLISP(with Cygwin) in Windows?

I *just* started trying out Sublime 2, I also *just* started learning LISP, and I've never used Cygwin before (finally picked it up cuz apparently it's the only way to run CLISP on Windows?) or BASH.

So probably the answer would be more obvious to someone who was already familiar with all (or any) of these tools.

Answer (score 0):

A working build file is the following JSON:

```
{
    "cmd":  ["clisp", "$file_name" ]
}
```

It's the use of `$file_name` rather than `$file` (`$file` as used in the first example on the page of [the Sublime 2 Build Systems Documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html#file-format)) that makes it work.

This would probably be obvious to anyone who didn't manage to be a dope and miss the list of [Build System Variable](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html#build-system-variables) way down the page until *after* they'd accidentally stumbled upon the right answer. xD